# Select rows with more than one relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id int,
  name varchar(200),
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id int,
  name varchar(200),
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE rel (
  id1 int,
  id2 int,
  value int,
  primary key (id1, id2),
  foreign key (id1) REFERENCES t(id),
  foreign key (id2) REFERENCES t2(id)
);
```

How should I query rows from `t` that satisfy more than 1 relationship with `t2`?
This sounds easy enough but I'm not sure what is the best practice in this case. I'll explain better with queries:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM t
INNER JOIN rel ON (t.id = rel.id1)
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = rel.id2)
WHERE (rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1)
```

The above works nicely when I need to find rows that satisfy one relationship. But now:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM t
INNER JOIN rel ON (t.id = rel.id1)
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t2.id = rel.id2)
WHERE (rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1)
AND (rel.id2 = 2 AND rel.value = 2)
```

With 2 relationships this query will never work as the joined rows will never have 2 different relationships in one row, so it will always return `0` rows.

The solution I've been using so far is looking for `t.id`s that are `IN` a result set from the relation:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM t
WHERE (t.id IN (SELECT id1 FROM rel WHERE rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1))
AND (t.id IN (SELECT id1 FROM rel WHERE rel.id2 = 2 AND rel.value = 2))
```

This works, but isn't there a better way around? I feel that I'm writing too much SQL and doing one sub-query for each item seems overkill for something so simple.

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cea83/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be over simplifying the issue, but could you not change an `AND` to an `OR` in your where clause and use `GROUP BY/HAVING` to get the number of relationships for a given criteria. e.g.

```
SELECT  t.id, t.name
FROM    t
        INNER JOIN rel 
            ON t.id = rel.id1
        INNER JOIN t2 
            ON t2.id = rel.id2
WHERE   (rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1)
OR      (rel.id2 = 2 AND rel.value = 1)
GROUP BY t.Id, t.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Although I would rewrite the where clause as:

```
WHERE   rel.Value = 1 
AND     rel.ID2 IN (1, 2)
```

**EDIT**

I would no longer rewrite the where clause above with the edited question. It would become

```
WHERE   (rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1)
OR      (rel.id2 = 2 AND rel.value = 2)
```

Comment: Oh never mind it was another guy that posted and deleted an answer with `having count(*) > 1`, nevertheless does indeed seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This is called Relational Division.

```
SELECT   t.id, t.name
FROM     t 
         INNER JOIN rel
            ON t.id = rel.id1
WHERE    rel.id2 IN (1,2) AND
         rel.value = 1
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
HAVING   COUNT(rel.id2) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4bbd8/5)
- [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Looks ok for my question, but what if the relationships have completely different values? That's my actual use-case.

Comment: can you expand this more *relationships have completely different values*?

Comment: I changed the value of the second relationship to 2 so it should match rows in `t` with the relationships `(rel.id2 = 1 AND rel.value = 1) AND (rel.id2 = 2 AND rel.value = 2)`

Comment: +1 I'll take the time to read the Relation Division article throughout later.